# OpenCover Profiler Error : ProfilerCommunication::RequestInformation(...) => Communication (Chat channel - TrackAssembly) with host has failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, code-coverage, .net-4.8, opencover

I am using OpenCover for code coverage for an ASP.NET MVC application on .NET 4.8. Code coverage works for sometime only where it shows coverage and most of the time is shows zero coverage with the same source code and command arguments.

As per online suggestion I tries using DebugView Application and noticed differences when it not works, following error is logged when it is not working and shows zero coverage

DebugView Log

```
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler) ProfilerCommunication::RequestInformation(...) => Communication (Chat channel - TrackAssembly) with host has failed (0x102, 60000)
```

---

```
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler)     ::Initialize(...) => CLSID == {1542C21D-80C3-45E6-A56C-A9C1E4BEB7B8}
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler)     ::Initialize(...) => EXE = C:\Users\MayankSaxena\AppData\Local\Iteration03\packages\msTestPlatform\16.9.1\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler)     ::Initialize(...) => PROFILER = C:\Users\MayankSaxena\AppData\Local\Iteration03\packages\openCover\4.7.922\tools\x86\OpenCover.Profiler.dll
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler)     ::Initialize(...) => key = 6E11F6D
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler) File Version: 4.7.922.0
[2440] 
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler) ProfilerCommunication::Initialise(...) => Initialised results interface => 6E11F6D1
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler) ::Initialize - Done!
[19636] OpenCover: (Host) Starting Process Block => 1
[19636] OpenCover: (Host) Started Process Block => 1
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler) ::ModuleLoadFinished(...) => Adding methods to mscorlib...
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler) ::ModuleLoadFinished(...) => Added methods to mscorlib
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler) cuckoo nest => mscorlib
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler) ProfilerCommunication::RequestInformation(...) => Communication (Chat channel - TrackAssembly) with host has failed (0x102, 60000)
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler) ::JITCompilationStarted(9FAC950, ...) => 100669944, A963DF8 => C:\Users\MayankSaxena\AppData\Local\Iteration03\build-output\DesignHub.Domain.dll
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler) ::JITCompilationStarted(9FACACC, ...) => 100669976, A963DF8 => C:\Users\MayankSaxena\AppData\Local\Iteration03\build-output\DesignHub.Domain.dll
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler) ::JITCompilationStarted(9FACB14, ...) => 100669982, A963DF8 => C:\Users\MayankSaxena\AppData\Local\Iteration03\build-output\DesignHub.Domain.dll
[2440] OpenCover: (Profiler) ::JITCompilationStarted(9FAC994, ...) => 100669950, A963DF8 => C:\Users\MayankSaxena\AppData\Local\Iteration03\build-output\DesignHub.Domain.dll
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.